# How to force download and count downloads in PHP

Tags: php

I have a file (.zip, .msi etc) on our server that we try and protect as much as possible. I know sessions can be spoofed, as well as referrer. We either require you to come from our download page (where session starts) or from one specific partner. I have all of this working. I wanted to insert Google Analytics but Ive read inserting js/html will corrupt the download. I would like to just create then write to a txt file and capture the date of each download and create a running count of total downloads. Here is my code to force the download - this is in a file that is directly called and doesn't take user off the partner website:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $refData = parse_url($ref);
    if(time() - $_SESSION['time'] < 2000 || ($refData['host'] == 'partnersite.com'))  {
        $path = '/var/www/vhosts/example.org/dir/dir/dir/App.Install.de-de.msi';
        $mm_type="Content-type: application/x-ole-storage";
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
        header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($path)) );
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
        readfile($path);

        //try and write to file and count downloads
        $current_count = file_get_contents('count');
        $f = fopen('count', 'w+');
        fwrite($f, $current_count + 1);
        fclose($f);

        exit();
    } else { ?>
        <?php header("Location: https://example.org/404.php");
        die(); ?>
    <?php }
?>
```

Again, this works exactly like I want it to in forcing and 'softly' protecting the download from hotlinking. Somewhere in there I need to create "count.php" write to it w/o over writing and then close it.

Comment: Note you can push hits to Google Analytics from PHP on the server side. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503329/is-there-any-way-to-post-events-to-google-analytics-via-server-side-api).

Comment: Maybe `file_put_contents('somefile.txt', $count, lock_constant_look.up.real.syntax.for.this);`?

Comment: @AlexHowansky - that looks very promising. I built a string in the "Hit Builder" tool, but not sure how to implement. Any example?

Comment: Are you asking _where_ and _how_ to write to a log file?

Comment: Yes, I know there are several examples, and I can get them to work on their own. I just can't figure out how to combine it with the working part I have already.

Comment: OK - To start, put it directly inside your `if` statement. Edit your question with what you have, even if it is not fully working. With that, we can assist further.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329531/php-making-a-download-counter-without-leaving-the-current-page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213940/php-count-downloads

Comment: @yivi - I looked at those links. However both seem to depend on a 'wrapper' file or link modification - passing file name through URL and output HTML. I don't want people to leave the 'parnter site'

Comment: @waterloomatt Added attempt (I know its wrong) at writing to a file and incrementally counting downlaods

Comment: This is racy. You should [lock the file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) during the update operation.

Comment: See also: https://dave.autonoma.ca/blog/2023/11/12/php-download-hit-counter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to keep track of `count` because you can simply count the lines of the file to see how many downloads there have been. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2162528/296555

```
if(time() - $_SESSION['time'] < 2000 || ($refData['host'] == 'partnersite.com'))  { 
    // Sudo code - see real example here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19898993/296555
    // Write to log file before initiating the download.
    $log = current date time
    file_put_contents('./log_file.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);

    // Now, do the download part
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `readfile()` you are surrendering control.

Do your logging **before** calling it, and it will work.

You can either keep a counter or write a log file. Since you already know how to write to a file, the details are up to you.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

Writing to a log is easy and can be done with the links provided in answers. I ended up needing a more robust solution, and one that worked with our existing Google Analytics set up. So I used Google's [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) and their [Hit Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) to test. Here is a [good source of info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499396/ga-e-commerce-tracking-in-php) from SO on it.